# removeFromSubView disables interaction

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView that is basically a chat log. I have an imageView in some of the cells and added the ability to expand an image to full screen on tap.

```
///
ChatLogMessageCell.swift


/**
*
* I add the target to the UIButton with an image as a background
*/

messageImage.addTarget(self, action: #selector(fullscreenImage), for: .touchUpInside)

/*
* Full screen code
*/
@objc func fullscreenImage() {

    if let chatlog = parentViewController as? ChatLogController {
        let imageScroll = UIScrollView()
        imageScroll.delegate = self
        imageScroll.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
        imageScroll.maximumZoomScale = 5.0
        imageScroll.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds

        let newImageView = UIImageView(image: messageImage.backgroundImage(for: .normal))
        newImageView.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
        newImageView.backgroundColor = .black
        newImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        newImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        imageScroll.addSubview(newImageView)

        chatlog.view.addSubview(imageScroll)
        chatlog.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
        chatlog.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissFullscreenImage))
            newImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

}

@objc func dismissFullscreenImage(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if let chatlog = parentViewController as? ChatLogController {
            chatlog.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
            chatlog.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
            sender.view?.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
```

When The fullscreen image is removed the ChatLogController is no longer interactable. I can't scroll or re-enter fullscreen mode on an image.What am I missing here? I simply want to dismiss the full screen image and allow the user to choose another image or just scroll through the messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you remove the imageView

```
sender.view?.removeFromSuperview()
```

while you need to remove the scrollView like

```
sender.view?.superview?.removeFromSuperview()
```

Comment: Ah!! Thank you so much. That did the trick. Can't believe I missed that. I knew something was on top of the collectionview. I tried bringSubviewToFront() and sendSubiewToBack, but couldn't figure it out! I'll accept the answer when I am able to.